# Error installing testacular with latest version of nodejs 0.8.19

Tags: installation, karma-runner

I get the following error when I run below command..

⚡ sudo **npm -g install testacular**

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at /usr/local/bin/npm:19:11
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/bin/npm:87:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing node.js - http://nodejs.org/download/

This happened to me after an old version of [n](https://npmjs.org/package/n) failed to install node `v0.10.5`, then I upgraded `n` and had it install node. It apparently didn't install `npm` quite correctly.